# Codeigniter: How can I create database driven URIs?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

My routes are language driven and look like this **mydomain.com/en**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

but I have database content that I would like to be in the URI after the language **mydomain.com/jp/the-slug-of-a-japanese-page**

I have a table called *posts* and it contains rows of content with title, slugs and languages ready to go but I don't fully get how to edit my home controller to check if the URI comes from the database.

Here is my home controller method.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
     public function index($title = '') {
       if(strlen($url)) {
        /* get content by title from DB */
        $data['url'] = $url;
        $this->load->view('user_home', $data);
       }
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but I think that you want to search a uri in your database, this is very simple:

```
function index()
{
    $needle = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->db->where('slug', $needle);
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    if($this->db->count_all_results() > 0)
    { //here the uri exists in your database }
    else
    { //here don't }
}
```

¿This might be what you need?

(of course that code should be in a model, not in the controller, to keep the MVC of codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this in controller

```
public function index($title = '') {

      if(strlen($url)) {
        /* get content by title from DB */
        /* load content view */
       }
   /* load index view */

}
```

Routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(\w{2})/(:any)'] = $route['default_controller'].'/index/$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not. $url isn't defined. Also I don't want it to route though to a folder called /index/

Comment: Its not index folder. Its the name of controller method